# Hiding base class method with "using" declaration doesn't work for assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, using, language-lawyer, method-hiding

Below is a simple example of how base methods are available in derived class:

```
struct Base {
  void foo ();
  Base& operator = (const Base&);
};

struct Derived : Base {
  // ...
};

int main () {
  Derived d1, d2;
  d1.foo();  // calls Base::foo
  d1 = d2;   // calls Base::operator =
}
```

If I add below statements in the body of `Derived` to hide both the methods, ...

```
struct Derived : Base {
  //...
private: // hide the below method for `Derived` objects
  using Base::foo;
  using Base::operator =;
}
```

... then the `Base::foo()` is hidden (becomes inaccessible) successfully.
But `Base::operator =` still remains *accessible*!!

```
d1.foo(); // error
d1 = d2;  // ok !!
```

<strike>The same phenomena is happening for other operators as well</strike>. Here is a [demo with g++](http://ideone.com/dcduZQ).

Shouldn't the accessibility rules (applied due to `using` keyword) apply to the methods and operators in the same way?
If not then what's the significance of the statement: `using operator =;`, is it simply ignored by the compiler?

**Update**:

1. My first thought was that, compiler might be generating its own
   default `Derived::operator =`. That's wrong because it uses
   `Base::operator =`.
2. If I use `private` inheritance, then `Base::foo()` is automatically
   hidden (even without `using`). But no effect on `Base::operator =`,
   it still works.

Please note that, I don't want solution for "how to hide it". But would like to understand from language point of view, why the operators are not hidden like other methods.

Comment: That's because there's no reason to look for the base operator. The derived class already has a perfectly serviceable assignment operator, implicitly.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I have clarified this part in the question. It doesn't use compiler generated `operator =`. Seems to be some other reason.

Comment: Let's leave the compiler out for now, it doesn't really play a role. The implicitly-defined `operator=` performs member-wise assignment, and also calls the assignment operators of the base classes, so you might not necessarily be able to tell.

Comment: And if you make the base assignment operator private, the implicitly-defined derived assignment operator is defined as deleted.

Comment: @KerrekSB, yes your 2nd comment makes sense to me. The compiler should be invoking the implicit `Derived::operator =` which in turn implicitly calls the `Base::operator =`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler will generate a default `operator=` for Derived class, and this implicit `Derived::operator=` in turn invokes `Base::operator=` internally.
To get rid of this, we need to disable the `operator=` explicitly:

```
struct Derived : Base {
  private: Derived& operator = (const Derived&);  // C++03 way
};

struct Derived : Base {
  Derived& operator = (const Derived&) = delete;  // C++11 way
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Update:
>   My first thought was that, compiler might be generating its own default Derived::operator =. That's wrong because it uses `Base::operator =`. Same holds true for other operators as well.
>
> If I use private inheritance, then `Base::foo()` is automatically hidden (even without using). But no effect on `Base::operator =`, it still works.

Your first though was correct. You didn't declare a copy assignment operator, so one was implicitly declared for you. You then *odr*-used that implicitly-declared copy assignment operator, so the compiler provided the implicitly-defined copy assignment operator. The implicitly-defined copy assignment operator of a struct or class performs a memberwise copy assignment of the class's base classes and then it's non-static data members.

That implicitly-defined copy assignment operator is a class member. It doesn't matter one bit that you have hidden the base class copy constructor to the outside world via `using` or via private inheritance because that base class assignment operator is visible to this implicitly-defined copy assignment operator.

Comment: Did you mean "assignment operator" at the places of "copy constructor"? Because we are doing assignment in the code.

Comment: Ooops. Yes. I'll fix that.